# Why can't I search my project database? - Various warnings

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can I just start off by saying I'm doing a computing course where one of the units is intro to PHP and that I'm JUST starting to get into PHP.

I'm very basic at this point, I have been tasked with making a site with a search page that you can search different movies etc.

**My production page (Search Page)**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Royal Theatre</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body> 

    <header>

        <img src="image/logo2.png">
    </header>

    <div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="Production"><a class="active" 
href="production.php">Production</a></li>
    <li class="Contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<h1>Search For Shows</h1>
<form action="presults.php" method="GET">
<br>
<label for="name" class="pd">Production Name:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
<label for="genre" class="gnr">Genre:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="genre">
<br>
<label for="date" class="dte">Date:</label>
<br>
<input type="date" name="date">
<br>
<label for="time" class="tme">Starting Time:</label>
<br>
<input type="date_list" name="time">



    <datalist id="production">


    <option value="Little Stars: Dance">
        <option value="RSNO Community Orchestra">
            <option value="Nicki Minaj">
                <option value="Harlem Globetrotters">
                    <option value="Alan Davies">
                        <option value="WWE">
                            <option value="Amazon Echo and the singing AI">
                                <option value="Spirited Away The Play">
                                    <option value="A Generic Stand Up Comedy 
Act">
                                        <option value="My Life Is A Joke">
                                            <option value="Rangers Football 
  Club">
                                                <option value="NEDs">
                                                    <option value="NZXT & 
The CAM Software">
                                                        <option 
value="Franky Boil Tribute Act">
                                                            <option 
value="Wee Archie & The Akitas">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />




    </form>


    <table>
        <?php

        echo "<TR><th>Production Reference</th> <th>Production Name</th> 
<th>Genre</th> <th>Date</th> <th>Starting Time</th> <th>Price Band</th>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $reference=$row['reference'];
            $name=$row['name'];
            $genre=$row['genre'];
            $date=$row['date'];
            $time=$row['time'];
            $pband=$row['pband'];
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$reference";?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$name";?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$genre";?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$date";?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$time";?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo "$pband";?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
    </table>






      <footer>
 © Scott
</footer>

</body>   
</html>
```

**My results php**

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['submit'])){

header('Location: production.php');
}else{

$name = $_GET['name'];
$genre = $_GET['genre'];
$time = $_GET['time'];
$date = $_GET['date'];


include'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT production.name, production.genre, production.date, production.time, price.adult, price.child, price.concession, price.pband FROM production, price WHERE production.name = '$name' AND production.genre = '$genre' AND production.date = '$date' AND production.time = '$time' AND production.pband = price.pband";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

?>



<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Production Results</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> </head>

<body>

<h1>Search Result</h1>

<table>




<th class="TH">Production Reference</th>
  <th class="TH">Production Name</th>
  <th class="TH">Genre</th>
  <th class="TH">Date</th>
  <th class="TH">Starting Time</th>
  <th class="TH">Price Band</th>

 <?php

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){echo"<tr> <td class='TD'>" . 'No Results 
Found' . "</td></tr>";}

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

 $date = $row['date'];
 $date = strtotime($date);
 $date = date('d-M-Y', $date);

       echo"<td class='TD'><a href='production.php'>Back to the main search 
page</a></td>";
echo "</table>"; 
    echo "<tr>


    <td class='TD'>" . $row['reference'] . "</td>
       <td class='TD'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
       <td class='TD'>" . $row['genre'] . "</td>
       <td class='TD'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
        <td class='TD'>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
       <td class='TD'>" . $row['pband'] . '" /> '. "</td>
     </tr>";

    }
echo"</table>";




}
?>
```

**My connection.php**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'theatre';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, "",$db);

if(!$con){

die("Connection Failed " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}else{
echo "";
}
?>
```

**The errors im getting when i search "WWE**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujOYf.png)

Any help at all is really greatly appreciated, I have been at this for hours on end and just can't see what the problem is.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: @AliRasheed sorry, i messed up the code indentation, its now there.

Comment: Perhaps your data isn't matching with database row. Search with only name. narrow down your searching criteria. And use `Joins`.

Comment: Every single one of those error messages has been discussed countless times already, and can easily be researched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS NOT ANSWER!

Try this query

```
$query = "SELECT name, genre, date, time, adult, child, concession, pr.pband FROM production p INNER JOIN price pr ON p.pband = pr.pband WHERE name LIKE '$name'";
```

ERROR in `myresult.php`

You have an error. In your `connection.php`you have defined `$con` as a connection variable but you used `$connection` in query.

It should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

WARNING in `connection.php`

you just have to pass variables do not put them in anything.it should be

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, "",$db);
```

Try using the query

```
$query = "SELECT reference, name, genre, date, time, pband FROM production p INNER JOIN price pr ON p.pband = pr.pband WHERE name LIKE '$name'";
```

Replace HTML of table

```
<td class='TD'>" . $row['reference'] . "</td>
   <td class='TD'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>
   <td class='TD'>" . $row['genre'] . "</td>
   <td class='TD'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
    <td class='TD'>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
   <td class='TD'>" . $row['pband'] . "</td>
 </tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped, now i dont get any errors when i search WWE, just a "no results found"

Comment: Show me a picture of rows in your database. And fast please I have to sleep

Comment: Okay try the query I have mentioned now! And also show me picture of price table

Comment: Please try the query again! I re-wrote it

Comment: This is what i get when i search WWE https://gyazo.com/1141b7c886e71a3ad26a620cacb45519

Comment: Now we're talking, shows the time etc but still a warning!  https://gyazo.com/e303464ae2fd4a753ec477aa0f56a6e9

Comment: You haven't selected reference. use the update query again

Comment: No, thank you! do you know how i can get rid of the a"/> at the end of it?

also how would i do it so i can search through all of the fields like genre and date etc? right now its only name

Comment: Check updated HTML! And keep your searching criteria low. Once you have firm grip on MYSQL and PHP then keep on getting advanced. Meanwhile this should be enough for you

Comment: I really appreciate your help, what do you mean by inner join and ON?